# Nuget (PowerShell 2.0 Error) Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10 (PwrShl 5.0)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, nuget, powershell-5.0

I am using `Visual Studio 2015`, on Windows 10 - I am having an issue running the `Nuget Console`, it wants `Powershell 2.0`. I do infact have powershell installed, but its version `5.0`

I don't really understand why 5 wouldn't be compatible with 2? or why nuget cant find 5 when 2 is not installed?

- I've tried install 2, didn't work
- I've tried the usual change permissions for nuget package signing, didn't work either

Any one got a suggestion? I'm sure it must be possible!

I need to download the latest Google Custom Search API, and it seems that Nuget is the only way to do it, but if not, then a link to direct download of the API would be just as useful for now! (I've got almost everything from google API, except search lol)

I've also tried installing the (Google Search API) packages manually via PowerShell 5.0, but it cant find them, as far as I am aware, the repositories should already be added, but perhaps not?

**Full Error Message:**

> Error: The Package Manager Console requires PowerShell 2.0 runtime, which is
>   not detected on this machine. Please install the PowerShell 2.0 from
>   support.microsoft.com/kb/968929 and restart Visual Studio

Comment: What error – the full message and a summary – are you getting?

Comment: going via Tools > Nuget > Package Manager Console ...I get: Error: The Package Manager Console requires PowerShell 2.0 runtime, which is not detected on this machine. Please install the PowerShell 2.0 from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929 and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Please include that information in full in the question.

Comment: done, although the error message does not provide any more information than I included in the question.

Answer (score 27):

You need to install `Powershell 2.0`. On `Windows 10` you can follow these steps:

1. Go to **This Pc**
2. Click **Uninstall or change a program** on computer tab
3. Click **Turn Windows features on or off**
4. Mark `Poweshell 2.0` for installation
5. Click **OK**

Or open powershell as admin and :

1. PS> Install-WindowsFeature PowerShell-V2

Comment: Yes, this worked. Annoying that Microsoft gives misinformation in Visual Studio stating that this needs to be downloaded.

Comment: Agreed, VS 2015 should detect that it is a platform feature and show appropriate error instead. The page it links to has no options for Windows 10.

Comment: The Cmdlet above for me, could not be found.. `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName "MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root" -Online -All` worked for me. 'online' - so it can download files; 'All' - so it can also install all (exactly 1) features under it, this feature is the PS 2.0 engine.